# This is the error I got when I try to open a map activity with a button?

Tags: android, google-maps, runtime-error

This is the error in the logcat...

```
02-29 16:01:35.490 9677-9677/com.example.deepaks.toggleswitch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.deepaks.toggleswitch, PID: 9677
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onbuttonclick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'Alert'
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:307)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:266)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

The code I used for opening the activity

```
public  void onbutttonclick(View s)
    {
        if (s.getId()==R.id.Alert)
        {
            Intent q= new Intent(toggle.this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(q);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Friend its been solved... I had an extra T in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method **onbuttonclick**(View)

and your function is

```
public  void onbutttonclick(View s)
```

it has an extra t in function defination. change it to :-

```
public  void onbuttonclick(View s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error:

```
onbutttonclick
```

too much "t"

You need to do

```
 onbuttonclick
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error for click event,
just simply use onbuttonclick() for the same.

Comment: Thank You friend...I had an extra T in it...
3 Days... hooo...
Thx a lot...